# Load different routes and config for several applications in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, routes, config, symfony4, bundles

So we currently use a custom CMS based on symfony 1 with several applications admin (backend) and www (frontend) but of course it's really time to move on and to use a new symfony version like symfony 4 as it's finally out.
I thought I would be cool using bundles instead of applications : one for www and one for admin but it seems that it's recommended to not use bundles anymore. Same thing with different kernels, it seems it's "better" to use a single one.

So I have to think about the architecture differently and I'm asking your help.
www and admin use a different domain and have their own routes and configuration but of course share the entities and some configuration.

1. About domains and routes I found ["How to Match a Route Based on the Host"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html) which is perfect.
2. Now can I do the same thing with configurations ? To load the "admin" config file and not the "www" config file when I use the "admin" domain ?
3. Same thing with bundles, it is possible to load some bundles for "admin" and some different ones for "www" ?
4. It would be nice if I could keep all those files in 2 separate folders (one with everything for admin and one for www) but is it possible ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

The configuration references give us this:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
            customer:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host2%'
                port:     '%database_port2%'
                dbname:   '%database_name2%'
                user:     '%database_user2%'
                password: '%database_password2%'
                charset:  UTF8
swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: second_mailer
    mailers:
        first_mailer:
            # ...
        second_mailer:
            # ...
```

For the configuration file you can split it in several files:

config_www.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        www:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8

swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        www_mailer:
            # ...
```

config_admin.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            admin:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     '%database_host%'
                port:     '%database_port%'
                dbname:   '%database_name%'
                user:     '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                charset:  UTF8
swiftmailer:
    mailers:
        admin_mailer:
            # ...
```

config.yml:

```
  imports:
    - { resource: www/config_www.yml }
    - { resource: admin/config_admin.yml }
```